# ¿Cuales son los equivalentes a 'hash' y 'hash_hmac' de PHP en NodeJS?

Tags: php, nodejs

Estoy tratando de convertir [este código PHP](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/6516521b1fb3b464534fbc30ea3573c2/raw/05216e3c3f985f7fa9295c5a0e5838afcbe67fb1/check_authorization.php) a javascript para NodeJS.

Pero al intentar comparar los hashes con 'localeCompare' me aparece el error 'Data is NOT from Telegram' ya que los hashes son diferentes.

Código PHP:

```php
<?php

define('BOT_TOKEN', 'XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // place bot token of your bot here

function checkTelegramAuthorization($auth_data) {
  $check_hash = $auth_data['hash'];
  unset($auth_data['hash']);
  $data_check_arr = [];
  foreach ($auth_data as $key => $value) {
    $data_check_arr[] = $key . '=' . $value;
  }
  sort($data_check_arr);
  $data_check_string = implode("\n", $data_check_arr);
  $secret_key = hash('sha256', BOT_TOKEN, true);
  $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data_check_string, $secret_key);
  if (strcmp($hash, $check_hash) !== 0) {
    throw new Exception('Data is NOT from Telegram');
  }
  if ((time() - $auth_data['auth_date']) > 86400) {
    throw new Exception('Data is outdated');
  }
  return $auth_data;
}

function saveTelegramUserData($auth_data) {
  $auth_data_json = json_encode($auth_data);
  setcookie('tg_user', $auth_data_json);
}


try {
  $auth_data = checkTelegramAuthorization($_GET);
  saveTelegramUserData($auth_data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ($e->getMessage());
}

header('Location: login_example.php');

?>
```

Código javascript:

```
const BOT_TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN
const crypto = require('crypto')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const checkTelegramAuthorization = (auth_data) => {
  const check_hash = auth_data.hash
  delete auth_data.hash
  const data_check_arr = []
  Object.keys(auth_data).forEach((key) => {
    data_check_arr.push(`${key}=${auth_data[key]}`)
  })
  data_check_arr.sort()
  const data_check_string = data_check_arr.join('\n')
  const secret_key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(BOT_TOKEN).digest('binary')
  const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret_key).update(data_check_string).digest('hex')
  if (hash.localeCompare(check_hash) !== 0) {
    throw new Error('Data is NOT from Telegram')
  }
  if ((Date.now() - Number(auth_data.auth_date)) > 86400) {
    throw new Error('Data is outdated')
  }
  return auth_data
}
const saveTelegramUserData = (response, auth_data) => {
  const auth_data_json = JSON.stringify(auth_data)
  response.cookie('tg_user', auth_data_json)
}

app.get('/tg/login', (request, response) => {
  try {
    auth_data = checkTelegramAuthorization(request.query)
    saveTelegramUserData(response, auth_data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.toString())
  }
  response.redirect('/')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente forma.

Resulta que para que la función [hash.digest()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding) de **crypto**, genere un hash en binario no se le debe pasar ningún valor. Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
const secret_key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(BOT_TOKEN).digest()
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret_key).update(data_check_string).digest('hex')
if (hash.localeCompare(check_hash) !== 0) {
  throw new Error('Data is NOT from Telegram')
}
```

Y con eso me valida correctamente el hash